# How can I transfer this plain text data to json data by python?

Tags: python, json

It may be a simple question to you. Pls take a look!

```
1. ad-intro of ad
prototype：intro of prototype 
aducir meaning of aducir   
variation：intro of variation
abreviar　meaning of abreviar
afiliar　meaning of afiliar
2. ab-intro of ab
prototype：ab-
abducir　meaning of abducir
abusar　meaning of abusar
variation：intro of variation
absceso　meaning of absceso
```

how can i transfer it to below array JSON data?
pls help!
I wanna use python to handle it. Could you help me with your python code?
Tks!

```
{
    "prefix":"ad",
    "intro":"intro of ad",
    "prototype":{
        "intro":"intro of prototype",
        "list":[
            {"word":"aducir","meaning":"meaning of aducir"}
        ]
    },
    "variation":{
        "intro":"intro of variation",
        "list":[
            {"word":"abreviar","meaning":"meaning of abreviar"},
            {"word":"afiliar","meaning":"meaning of afiliar"}
        ]
    }

}
{
    like above...
}
```

Comment: first parse the data, convert it to key-value pair, then use `json.dump()`

Comment: start by using `split` to get a list of all the rows of your data. you need to show some effort to fix the problem for me to help you

Answer (score 0):

you need to parse the string or file .  But you can't simply , because your data do not have infor to costruct a `dict`.

Your data have 6 lines  and your json template do not needs 6 keys .

Your data have some repeated words tha can help you to understand when use a key or another to craete a `dict`

Here in the picture,
in red , you can see missing parts.
In green , parts you have in the data.

With colored ellipse,  repeated words .

Many clues on how to analyze your data.

[image]

So your Json  will be  first a `dict` with `list` inside.

You can find string in a string (or in a line in this case)  in this way:

`bolean_result = your_word in your_string  # ->  return True or False`

So crete a dict with list  as you need  parsing your data.
To parse you data need `split` method

You can use `split` to split by line ,your data , or by 'empty spaces' , or 'commas'

here you can see some example on how to create JSON  : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/read-write-and-parse-json-using-python/

But ok ,  you can use this to start understanding the process

```
#importing the lib 're' to use regular expressions 
import re

#put your data string into a `data` multiline string variable 

data="""
1. ad-intro of ad
prototype：intro of prototype 
aducir meaning of aducir   
variation：intro of variation
abreviar　meaning of abreviar
afiliar　meaning of afiliar
2. ab-intro of ab
prototype：ab-
abducir　meaning of abducir
abusar　meaning of abusar
variation：intro of variation
absceso　meaning of absceso"""


#Data have more records separated by number followed by a period
#Divide the string by any number followed by a period using regexp `re`

records = re.split('\d\.',data)
for i,rec in enumerate(records):
    print(i,rec)
    print("")
```

#I have used  `enumerate` to view the number of records found .

output1:

```
0 


1  ad-intro of ad
prototype：intro of prototype 
aducir meaning of aducir   
variation：intro of variation
abreviar　meaning of abreviar
afiliar　meaning of afiliar


2  ab-intro of ab
prototype：ab-
abducir　meaning of abducir
abusar　meaning of abusar
variation：intro of variation
absceso　meaning of absceso
```

#as you can se in **output1** records 0 is empty. We do not need it

#let me try again

```
records = re.split('\d\.',data)
for i,rec in enumerate(records[1:]):  #so we start from 1 , not from 0 in this way
    print(i,rec)
```

output2:

```
0  ad-intro of ad
prototype：intro of prototype 
aducir meaning of aducir   
variation：intro of variation
abreviar　meaning of abreviar
afiliar　meaning of afiliar

1  ab-intro of ab
prototype：ab-
abducir　meaning of abducir
abusar　meaning of abusar
variation：intro of variation
absceso　meaning of absceso
```

#Nice we have 2 records . We can pass any useful record to a function that will parse the record.

#Let me try again creating the parse_record function

```
def parse_record(rec):
    #using split by new line to obtain lines
    lines = rec.split("\n")
    for i,l in enumerate(lines):
        print(i,l)

    print("")



records = re.split('\d\.',data)

#so we start from 1 , not from 0 in this way `records[1:]`

for i,rec in enumerate(records[1:]):  
    #call the function we have created
    parse_record(rec)
```

output3:

```
0  ad-intro of ad
1 prototype：intro of prototype 
2 aducir meaning of aducir   
3 variation：intro of variation
4 abreviar　meaning of abreviar
5 afiliar　meaning of afiliar
6 

0  ab-intro of ab
1 prototype：ab-
2 abducir　meaning of abducir
3 abusar　meaning of abusar
4 variation：intro of variation
5 absceso　meaning of absceso
```

and so on ...    my be you understand  what you have in the 0,1,2,3,4,5 lines ...  You need to manipulate string  to create the `dict`

Comment: Tks for you help, but dict of python and creating JSON is not the point of this question. In fact, this code above is the simpler version of my real code. The key point is I don't konw how to deal with text document to the 'list' json array as you can see.

Comment: You can't create the json from your text data directly. You need to parse first. You need to know what it means to parse. you can do this if you know how to use the split function, the join function, and how to know if a string is present inside a larger string. You need to know how to use conditions like "if elif else". You need to know how to loop a list using 'for' and of course combine the logic using these functions to get the result. The first result you need to get is a python object, made up of a 'dict' that has one or more 'lists' inside. ... ... ...

Comment: When you have done this, you will eventually be able to use the 'json' methods or functions to create your json. If you don't know any of these things, the goal you want to achieve is not within your reach. At the moment I can help you by just telling you to find out how to use the functions I have listed. If you already know them then prove that you use them, even badly. After I will be happy to correct you and write your code well. This site is not a free software development service. You have not currently written any code that demonstrates a minimum of effort on your part.

Comment: Sorry for my rudeness, it's my first time to use this site, I didn't see your whole answer. It seems I need to take a time to view your whole answer. Anyway, good job my bro, Tks!